# CascadeType doesn't work in in-memory database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a webapp with database where two Entities have many-to-many relationship but I implemented join table manually. When one of the entities gets deleted it deletes all entries in the join table and updates the other entity so all works perfectly fine, but now I'm supposed to write a test for this feature. For tests I am using in-memory database and that's really the only difference, the same methods with the same annotations (and cascade types) are called but I keep getting:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FKC17477FD8940DF2B table ENTITY1_ENTITY2
```

I didn't paste any code as I don't believe there is anything wrong with it since it's working. I don't ask to fix this for me, I just need to know what is likely to cause this kind of behavior because I've just ran out of ideas and I don't know what else to search for... Thanks

EDIT: here's some code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "interviewer")
public class Interviewer implements Identifiable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "interviewer_id")
    private Collection<InterviewerTechnology> technologies;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "technology")
public class Technology implements Identifiable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "technology_id")
    private Collection<InterviewerTechnology> technologies;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "interviewer_technology")
public class InterviewerTechnology implements Identifiable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Interviewer interviewer;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Technology technology;
}

@Component
public class TechnologyDao extends AbstractEntityDao<Technology> {

    public void remove(Integer id) {
        Technology technology = find(id);
        em.remove(technology);
    }
}
```

This code does exactly what I want it to do, it just seems like database used for tests does not see CascadeType parameters that do all the job here

Comment: It would still be a lot easier for us if you showed us the code.

Comment: ok, will paste relevant pieces

Comment: Try CascadeType.PERSIST

Comment: It's the same as if I changed it go CascadeType.ALL - breaks in the application, still doesn't work in tests

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and show what statements are issued.  The mappings look incorrect though if the InterviewerTechnology is meant to be like a relation table. Instead of defining the join column on the OneToMany, it should instead specify that it is mappedby the other side.  Otherwise you are telling JPA there are two separate relationships between Technology and InterviewerTechnology, and it could be this that is causing your issue on the in-memory database.

Comment: I did the change you suggested - code still works, test still breaks. In the SQL log there no sinle DELETE work even though I am deleting entity, so it's just brought more confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and it was `@Transactional` annotation. All my test `DAOs` were extending generic test `DAO` which was annotated with `@Transactional` and I blindly annotated every single `DAO` with it again. The problem here is that some operations need to be performed as single transactions (may need `flush()` after being executed) so that data is available for other operations straight away. Consider following example:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractEntityDao<E> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "some-persistence")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public E create(E e) {
        em.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
    (...)
}
```

which means that every method in this class is a transaction. Now if we annotate another class that extends this class with `@Transactional` every method will be another transaction, which means if we delete several things in one method it should take several transactions (they all need `flush()` method to be called in order to execute cascade) but instead they will run as one transaction (unless we specify `Propagation`). Let this be a lesson for everyone (especially me) to think carefully about which operations need separate transactions and which can be executed as one.